# GWT: How to run code after sorting a datagrid column

Tags: gwt, sorting

I really need a possibility to run some code after the whole sorting of the DataGrid is finished. Especially after the little arrow which shows if the column is sorted ascending or descending is displayed, because i need to manipulate the CSS of this arrow after it is displayed. I couldn't find the place where the arrow is really set. I tried something like this:

```
ListHandler<String> columnSortHandler = new ListHandler<String>(list) {
    @Override
    public void onColumnSort( ColumnSortEvent event ) {
        super.onColumnSort( event );
        // My Code here
    }
};
```

but the code runs also before sorting finishes.

Thanks for any suggestions how to solve this problem. I am searching for a long time now but cannot find anything that helps.

EDIT: I already override the original `DataGrid.Resources` to provide a custom arrow-picture. I also have a complex custom header of `AbstractCell<String>` which supports runtime-operations and is rendered with DIV's and Image.

Comment: What kind of style manipulation do you need to do? Can't you simply use a custom `cellTableSortedHeaderAscending` and `cellTableSortedHeaderDescending` styles providing a custom `CellTable.Resources`, possibly in combination with `setColumnStyleName`?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer My table and headers are very custom and i already override the Resources and Styles of the original DataGrid but need to access the DIV-container with the arrow-image over DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're using a `ListHandler`, and thus probably a `ListDataProvider` that will update the `CellTable` *live* (`setRowData`); because both `ListDataProvider` and `CellTable` (*via* the inner `HasDataPresenter`) use `Scheduler#scheduleFinally()`, then using `Scheduler#scheduleDeferred()` should be enough to guarantee that you run after them, but then you'll risk some flicker.

You could, in your custom `ListHandler` `flush()` the  `ListDataProvider`, which will bypass one `scheduleFinally` and then use `scheduleFinally` to execute after the one of the `CellTable` (because `flush()` will call `setRowData` on the `CellTable` which will schedule the command; your command wil be scheduled after, so will run after).

Comment: The possibility with `flush()` sounds good, but how can i schedule a command like `DOM.getElementById(getElementId()).getParentElement()` with this `flush()`? Thought it only updates the content of the table!?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem! Don't care about that comment above ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the css resource using `CellTable.Resources`.

```
public interface TableResources extends CellTable.Resources {
@Source("up.png")
ImageResource cellTableSortAscending();

@Source("down.png")
ImageResource cellTableSortDescending();

@Source("MyCellTable.css")
CellTable.Style cellTableStyle();
```

}

In `MyCellTable.css` use the stylename and change your icon

Comment: Tanks for answer but i already use this `DataGrid.Resources` and CSS. I have a complex `AbstractCell<String>`-Header which also have some Icons and is sometimes aligned right or center and includes two other DIVs. I really need to run code after the sorting finishes to access this arrow with DOM and manipulate it after it is displayed.